# How to set diffrent-diffrent values in SASS?

Tags: css, while-loop, sass

Hello i was try to create padding-top classes using while loop working fine but my query is when loop value is absolute than print this class like : **.padding-top-5{padding-top:5%}** after than when vlaue in point than i want print this out-put add this one '**half-**' word in class name when value in point like this one: **.padding-top-half-5{padding-top:5%}**. Any solution please help me. Thanks in adavance.

SASS code here:

```
$spacing-top: 5;
@while $spacing-top < 7 {
  .padding-top-#{$spacing-top} {
    padding-top: unquote(#{$spacing-top})+'%';
  }
  $spacing-top: $spacing-top + 0.5;
}
```

CSS Out-put here:

```
.padding-top-5{padding-top:5%}
.padding-top-5.5{padding-top:5.5%}
.padding-top-6{padding-top:6%}
.padding-top-6.5{padding-top:6.5%}
```

I want this type of class name:

```
.padding-top-5{padding-top:5%}
.padding-top-half-5.5{padding-top:5.5%}
.padding-top-6{padding-top:6%}
.padding-top-half-6.5{padding-top:6.5%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dharmesh I tried another solution and i think this is better, please check it once.

```
$spacing-top: 5;
@while $spacing-top < 10 {
    .padding-top-#{$spacing-top} {
        padding-top: unquote(#{$spacing-top})+'%';
    }

    $halfValue: $spacing-top + 0.5;
    .padding-top-#{$spacing-top}-half {
        padding-top: unquote(#{$halfValue})+'%';
    }
    $spacing-top: $spacing-top + 1;
}
```

Out will be:

```
.padding-top-5 {
  padding-top: 5%;
}
.padding-top-5-half {
  padding-top: 5.5%;
}
.padding-top-6 {
  padding-top: 6%;
}
.padding-top-6-half {
  padding-top: 6.5%;
}
.padding-top-7 {
  padding-top: 7%;
}
.padding-top-7-half {
  padding-top: 7.5%;
}
.padding-top-8 {
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.padding-top-8-half {
  padding-top: 8.5%;
}
.padding-top-9 {
  padding-top: 9%;
}
.padding-top-9-half {
  padding-top: 9.5%;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also working fine. Thanks for spending your valuable time.

Answer (score 3):

**Finally got answer help with programmers special thanks Satish Dubariya & Aasim Goriya.**

```css
$spacing-top: 5;
$full: '';
$half : false;
@while $spacing-top < 7 {
  @if $half {
    $full : '-half';
    $half: false;
  } @else {
    $full: '';
    $half: true;
  }
  .padding-top#{$full}-#{floor($spacing-top)} {
    padding-top: unquote(#{$spacing-top})+'%';
  }
  $spacing-top: $spacing-top + 0.5;
}
```